# Adding to the Chef Gem Source?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

My organization works entirely within the firewall (i.e, no machines have internet access). Whenever chef cookbooks are update and require gems the recipes fail due to the fact they cannot download and install gems from rubygems.org.

We self host copies of required gems - how can we add a custom internal source to chef, so that we don't have to deal with failures?

Comment: are you using anything like chef-dk? or berkshelf?

Comment: You wouldn't add it to Chef - you would add a gemrc file to all your systems (probably using Chef) that points to your internal gem server.

Comment: Where would be put the gemrc file? We only have windows systems in our chef environment (~150) nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the gemrc for the embedded Ruby with Chef Client.

```
chef_etc_dir = Chef::Util::PathHelper.join(Chef::Config.embedded_dir, 'etc')
chef_gemrc   = Chef::Util::PathHelper.join(chef_etc_dir, 'gemrc')

directory chef_etc_dir do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
end.run_action(:create)

file chef_gemrc do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  content <<EOF
---
:sources:
- https://path.to.internal.repo/
- https://rubygems.org
:update_sources: true
EOF
  end.run_action(:create)
```

The PathHelper methods should give appropriate paths for either Windows or Linux.

The ".run_action(:create)" addition executes the resources at compile time, not converge time, to ensure subsequent chef_gem resources will have access to the newly-managed gemrc at converge time.

Update: Chef appears to recommend the [rubygems cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/rubygems) to perform this functionality.

```
gemrc :global do
  values(
    sources: %w{ https://path.to.internal.repo https://rubygems.org }
  )
end
```

Comment: Does the rubygems cookbook get us around the changed rubygems upstream source problems that have plagued us since 2017?